# Mysql query with a column name having '%' sign in it not executing in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, web

I have a Mysql query as follows

```
$query = "UPDATE student_database SET fname='$fname',mname='$mname',lname='$lname',dob='$dob',Age='$age',Sex='$sex',Caste='$caste',dept='$dept', SSC%=$ssc , HSC%=$hsc, ATKTs=$atkt, Last_sem%=$lastsem, Aggregate%=$agg WHERE student_id=$id  ; ";
```

Some column names have a '%' sign in it. Mysql throws the following error when I execute it

```
Cannot execute.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%=79.6 , HSC%=81.83, ATKTs=5, Last_sem%=52.35, Aggregate%=53.6 WHERE student_id=' at line 1
```

Can't figure out the problem I have tried "\" , "#" , "%%" as escape characters but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in backticks to tell SQL that it's a column, does this work?

```
$query = "UPDATE student_database SET fname='$fname',mname='$mname',lname='$lname',dob='$dob',Age='$age',Sex='$sex',Caste='$caste',dept='$dept', `SSC%`=$ssc , `HSC%`=$hsc, ATKTs=$atkt, `Last_sem%`=$lastsem, `Aggregate%`=$agg WHERE student_id=$id  ; ";
```

Comment: Thank you KAVISIEGEL that helped. Can you please explain what the problem was?

Comment: In MySQL queries, in order to say that something is a column, it can be wrapped in backticks. Note how in the code above, it says `\`SSC%\`` where in your code, it says `SSC%`

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the column names in backticks, e.g

```
`SSC%`=$ssc
```